# Does OG Mailing List "Domain Name" configuration setting allow different mail list address than address Drupal is installed under

Tags: 7, organic-groups, emails

Does OG Mailing List "Domain Name" configuration setting allow different mail list address than address Drupal is installed under

In OG Mailinglist 7.x-1.1-alpha2 for Drupal 7 there is a setting under OG Mailinglist configuration called "Domain Name".  This allows you to set the domain name for incoming/outgoing emails as seen here

[image]

I didn't see in the documentation on OG Mailinglist any details about this configuration option.  Intuitively you would think that it would allow you to have a different domain name set up for your mail lists than the domain name that Drupal is currently installed under.

I am curious if anyone has done this and set up a different domain name for their mail lists as per this configuration setting than the domain that Drupal is installed under?

I could change the domain name in this configuration option to be different from our current environment we are developing under, but we would then have to update our mail exchange record, which costs money and it a bit complicated, since we currently only have the Domain name for incoming and outgoing mail to be the same as the domain name that Drupal is installed under.

If you have done this can you respond and let me know that this configuration option really works?

Thanks,